# How can I get relevant experience during undergrad if professors at my school don't study what I'm interested in

Tags: graduate-admissions, undergraduate

I'm interested in pursuing a PhD in clinical psychology, but there aren't any professors doing clinical psych research where I'm going to school. I'm at a top university, and I'd like to get into a prestigious PhD program. I don't know how to set myself up for that though, trying to reconcile what I'm interested in, what my school supports, and what's hot in the field right now.

Comment: Can you transfer to a school where people do the research you're interested in? I'm surprised a top university wouldn't have people in clinical psychology in some sense, though.

Comment: Any research experience is useful, though. Very few people do exactly what they did as undergraduates when they go to graduate school.

Comment: Is this about the US? And are you an undergraduate currently?

Comment: @BryanKrause - and very few people do exactly what they did as PhD students through the rest of their career... But, an undergrad doesn't know enough of what is out there to really know the totality of what is or will be interesting to them. 40 years in I'm still finding new interesting things.

Comment: @JonCuster Indeed. https://phdcomics.com/comics/archive.php?comicid=2031 https://phdcomics.com/comics/archive.php?comicid=967

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, it is normal that no one at the university has the same interest as you. However, it does not mean that they cannot supervise you on the topic that you are interested. You have to ask them first.

Secondly, I used to think that I should only do (undergraduate) research in the field that I liked the most in order to prepare for graduate application. I was wrong. If you want to become a good clinical psychology researcher, you need to become a good researcher **first**. You need to know how to do research; philosophical stuff; how to cite papers; how to read papers; how to do literature review; critical thinking; etc.

That is why any research experience is immensely useful. As a pre-PhD student, the domain knowledge that you learn from a particular research project may not be as important as the research experience - which will be useful for a lifetime and not limited to any discipline/topic. Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

Other than what others in the thread have said, you can always approach professors from other universities and talk to them about what you're interested in, and that you're willing to research for free, this will 1) give you experience and 2) give you a connection and a possible recommendation. Basically, it doesn't have to come from the same university where you got your degree.